# (jQuery) Multiple Append Not Work

Tags: jquery

I have the code to automatically change the color of certain text to append color. In addition, I also add append ondblclick.

Here are some of my code:

```
<div class="post-body">

<div id="kangSigit">
<div id="jHtml">CODE 1</div>
<div id="iHtml">
function example() {<br />
$(this).append("example")<br />
}
</div></div>

<br /><br />

<div id="kangSigit">
<div id="jHtml">CODE 2</div>
<div id="iHtml">
function example() {<br />
$(this).append("example")<br />
}
</div></div>

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#kangSigit").ready(function() {
    var a = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        b = /function/gi,
        c = "<span class='Func'>function</span>",
        d = a.replace(b, c);
    $("#kangSigit").html(d);
    var e = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        f = /var /gi,
        g = "<span class='iVar'>var </span>",
        h = e.replace(f, g);
    $("#kangSigit").html(h);
    var i = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        j = /document/gi,
        k = "<span class='iDoc'>document</span>",
        l = i.replace(j, k);
    $("#kangSigit").html(l);
    var m = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        n = /{/gi,
        o = "<span class='iKb'>{</span>",
        p = m.replace(n, o);
    $("#kangSigit").html(p);
    var q = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        r = /}/gi,
        s = "<span class='iKt'>}</span>",
        t = q.replace(r, s);
    $("#kangSigit").html(t);
    var u = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        v = /&lt;/gi,
        w = "<span class='iKb2'>&lt;</span>",
        x = u.replace(v, w);
    $("#kangSigit").html(x);
    var y = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        z = /&gt;/gi,
        A = "<span class='iKt2'>&gt;</span>",
        B = y.replace(z, A);
    $("#kangSigit").html(B);
    var C = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        D = /type /gi,
        E = "<span class='iTy'>type </span>",
        F = C.replace(D, E);
    $("#kangSigit").html(F);
    var G = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        H = /replace/gi,
        I = "<span class='iRep'>replace</span>",
        J = G.replace(H, I);
    $("#kangSigit").html(J);
    var K = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        L = /remove/gi,
        M = "<span class='iRem'>remove</span>",
        N = K.replace(L, M);
    $("#kangSigit").html(N);
    var O = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        P = /textarea/gi,
        Q = "<span class='iTe'>textarea</span>",
        R = O.replace(P, Q);
    $("#kangSigit").html(R);
    var S = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        T = /this/gi,
        U = "<span class='iThi'>this</span>",
        V = S.replace(T, U);
    $("#kangSigit").html(V);
    var W = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        X = /\$/gi,
        Y = "<span class='jQ'>$</span>",
        Z = W.replace(X, Y);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Z);
    var _ = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        ab = /\(/gi,
        bb = "<span class='iKb3'>(</span>",
        cb = _.replace(ab, bb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(cb);
    var db = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        eb = /\)/gi,
        fb = "<span class='iKt3'>)</span>",
        gb = db.replace(eb, fb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(gb);
    var hb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        ib = /append/gi,
        jb = "<span class='iAp'>append</span>",
        kb = hb.replace(ib, jb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(kb);
    var lb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        mb = /innerHTML/gi,
        nb = "<span class='iNht'>innerHTML</span>",
        ob = lb.replace(mb, nb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(ob);
    var pb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        qb = /getElementById/gi,
        rb = "<span class='iGet'>getElementById</span>",
        sb = pb.replace(qb, rb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(sb);
    var tb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        ub = /fadeIn/gi,
        vb = "<span class='fIn'>fadeIn</span>",
        wb = tb.replace(ub, vb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(wb);
    var xb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        yb = /fadeOut/gi,
        zb = "<span class='fOut'>fadeOut</span>",
        Ab = xb.replace(yb, zb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Ab);
    var Bb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Cb = /if/gi,
        Db = "<span class='Xif'>if</span>",
        Eb = Bb.replace(Cb, Db);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Eb);
    var Fb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Gb = /else/gi,
        Hb = "<span class='Els'>else</span>",
        Ib = Fb.replace(Gb, Hb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Ib);
    var Jb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Kb = /alert/gi,
        Lb = "<span class='alrt'>alert</span>",
        Mb = Jb.replace(Kb, Lb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Mb);
    var Nb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Ob = /onclick/gi,
        Pb = "<span class='iOnc'>onclick</span>",
        Qb = Nb.replace(Ob, Pb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Qb);
    var Rb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Sb = /ondblclick/gi,
        Tb = "<span class='iDbl'>ondblclick</span>",
        Ub = Rb.replace(Sb, Tb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Ub);
    var Vb = $("#kangSigit").html(),
        Wb = /click/gi,
        Xb = "<span class='clck'>click</span>",
        Yb = Vb.replace(Wb, Xb);
    $("#kangSigit").html(Yb);
    $("#iHtml").attr("ondblclick", "selTxt('iHtml')");
    $("#iScript").attr("ondblclick", "selTxt('iScript')");
    $("#iCss").attr("ondblclick", "selTxt('iCss')");
});

function selTxt(a) {
    if (document.selection) {
        var b = document.body.createTextRange();
        b.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(a)), b.select()
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var b = document.createRange();
        b.selectNode(document.getElementById(a)), window.getSelection().addRange(b)
    }
}
</script>
```

[Examples of results](http://www.kangsigit.com/p/editor.html?filename=not_work_part2)

If on one page there is only one code, then it is able to walk normally. However, when I try to make the two codes was only the first code that works.

Please give a solution to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Those `function example() {<br />` are wrong!

Comment: @void - It was just an example of one code that is placed in it and in my opinion has no effect